# Field not available in Lead field mapping when converting

Tags: leads, lead-conversion

I'm trying to map a picklist field on Lead to a matching picklist field on Opportunity when doing the conversion.  This field doesn't seem to be available when going to 'Map Lead fields'.  Could this be because the Opportunity field has a field dependency and so would stop the conversion/insert of the opp?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question in a knowledgebase article.

http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000229308

The gist of it:  Standard Lead Fields cannot map to Custom Opportunity/Contact/Account fields.